# Difference of disable form

Tags: c#

```
this.Enabled = false;
```

When I used it in initialiser, form was disactived but can move or close.
Using in code (call by button click event), all was disabled including form move or close.

Using debug mode, I checked 'this' (i thought it may be different) but it was almost same.

What is different between using in initialiser and public code?

Comment: Can you show code which reproduces your problem?

Comment: I made simple test project. http://goo.gl/J3PaaJ

Comment: When you set `Enabled = false` in constructor, window handle is not yet created. Perhaps doing it this way will not disable window system menu (or mouse event), because there is not window (and menu) yet. This should be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

check Locked property in both case.

```
this.Locked;
```